# lftp delete multiples files with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, xargs, lftp

I try to create a script who delete all the olds files except the three more recent files on my backup directory with lftp.

I have try to do this with `ls -1tr` who return all the files in ascending date order, and after I do a `head -$NB_BACKUP_TO_RM` ($NB_BACKUP_TO_RM is the numbers of files that I want to delete in my lists), this two commands return the correct files.

After this I want to remove all of them, so I do a `xargs rm --`, but Bash returns that the files don't exist... I think this command is not running into the remote directory, but in the local directory, and I don't know what I can do for delete this files (of my return lists).

Here is the full code:

```
MAX_BACKUP=3
NB_BACKUP=$(lftp -e "ls -1tr $REMOTE_DIR/full_backup_ftp* | wc -l ; quit" -u $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST)

if (( $NB_BACKUP > $MAX_BACKUP ))
then
   NB_BACKUP_TO_RM=$(($NB_BACKUP-$MAX_BACKUP))
   REMOVE=$(lftp -e "ls -1tr $REMOTE_DIR/full_backup_ftp* | head -$NB_BACKUP_TO_RM | xargs rm -- ; quit" -u $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST)
   echo $REMOVE
fi
```

Have you an idea of the problem? How can I delete the files of my lists (after `ls -1tr $REMOTE_DIR/full_backup_ftp*` and `head -$NB_BACKUP_TO_RM`)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks xargs is unknown cmd for lftp after `man lftp`. And `xargs rm` is deleting local files not remote files.

so please use xargs as below, it works for me.

```
lftp -e "ls -1tr $REMOTE_DIR/full_backup_ftp*; quit" -u $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST | head -$NB_BACKUP_TO_RM | xargs -I {} lftp -e 'rm '{}'; quit' -u $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST
```

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer, I doesn't know the usage of `xargs -I` who permit to send rm command to each of my files, it work perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

Starting SFTP connection can be time consuming. Slightly modified solution to avoid multiple lftp sessions below. It will perform much better the the alternative solution, especially if large number of files have to be purged.

Basically, leveraging lftp flexibility to mix lftp command with external commands. It creates a command file with a series of 'rm' (leveraging head ,xargs, ...), and executing those commands INSIDE the same lftp session.

Also note that lftp 'ls' does not allow wildcard, use 'cls' instead

**Make sure you test this carefully, because of potential removal of important files**

```
lftp -e $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST <<__CMD__
   cls -1tr $REMOTE_DIR/full_backup_ftp* | head -$NB_BACKUP_TO_RM | xarg -I{} echo rm {} > rm_list.txt
   source rm_list.txt
__CMD__
```

Or with one liner, using 'lftp' ability to execute dynamically generated command (source -e). It eliminate the temporary file.

```
lftp -e $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST <<__CMD__
   source -e 'cls -1tr $REMOTE_DIR/full_backup_ftp* | head -$NB_BACKUP_TO_RM | xarg -I{} echo rm {}'
__CMD__
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like this approch but I have two corrections :
`lftp -e $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST` replace the `-e` with `-u`
And for `xarg` replace into `xargs`.
Also your first method with the `rm_list.txt` work great, but the second method return `cls command not found` have you an idea of why ?
Also with the first method I have try with `cls` and `ls`, both return the same data, are you sure that `ls` doesn't allow wildcard ? because it seem to work on my script.
In any case thanks for your help and answer.